# Is there a way to set an empty Allow header that is not omitted in the response?

Tags: c#, http-headers, http-status-code-405, response-headers, httpresponsemessage

I have a .net service endpoint to return a list of entities with a GET request. However I do require an OData filter option to be defined, as I don't support a query for all the entities. If a request without a filter is sent, my service will return a 405 response. [Http spec says that 405 responses must define an Allow header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405), but there's no other allowed method in this entity. Fortunately, [I see that the Allow header can also be defined as empty](https://stackoverflow.com).

So this is what I am trying to do, I want to define the Allow header field as an empty string.

I see that `HttpRequestMessage.Headers` cannot have the Allow field defined, as the Allow field is a Content Header field, so I've tried defining it as the following:

- `response.Content.Headers.Add("Allow", string.Empty);`
- `response.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Allow", string.Empty);`
- `response.Content.Headers.Append(new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>("Allow", new List<string>()));`

However, in all of these cases, if I ask: `Assert.IsTrue(msg.Content.Headers.Contains("Allow"));`, it fails.

Is there a way to force the empty header to be sent out? Or am I looking at this completely in the wrong way?

Comment: Are you sure 405 is the most appropriate HTTP status for this scenario? Normally it means that the client is using a verb not supported by the endpoint (e.g. server is expecting a POST but the client sent a GET). 403 or 400 might be more appropriate statuses. Or if you really want to use 405, set the value of the Allow header to the list of acceptable verbs, i.e. GET.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understood why  you want this but i think that the right way as follows:

`response.Content.Headers.Allow.Add(string.Empty);`

Comment: `response.Content.Headers.Allow.Add(string.Empty)` throws an `ArgumentException` with message `The value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: item`.